# Sql Query for Updation on Selection

Tags: sql

I created  2 table as follows

Table `ForgeRock`:

```
id  status  amount    Name            date
1     0      4500     ram           04/02/2012
2     0      2000    shyam          05/09/2013
4     0      1500    ghanshyam      08/06/2015
```

Table `ForgeRock1`:

```
id   status   amount    Name          date
3      0      4500     gopal       04/02/2012
2      0      8000   radheshyam    15/11/2013
4      1      1500    ghanshyam    08/06/2015
```

Sql query

```
Select f1.id,
      case when f1.status = 1 then f1.status else 

f2.status end as Status,
     case when f1.status = 1 then f1.amount else 

f2.amount end as rank,
      f1.Name,
      case when f1.status = 1 then f1.date else 

f2.date end as date
      from ForgeRock f1
 inner join ForgeRock1 f2 on f1.id = f2.id and 

f1.Name=f2.Name 

     union all


 Select id,
      Status,
      amount,
      Name,
      date
      from ForgeRock
   where id not in (select distinct id from 

ForgeRock1)

union all

 Select id,
      Status,
      amount,
      Name,
      date
      from ForgeRock1
   where id not in (select distinct id from 

ForgeRock)

union all

Select f1.id,
      case when f1.status = 1 then f1.status else 

f2.status end as Status,
     case when f1.status = 1 then f1.amount else 

f2.amount end as rank,
      f1.Name,
      case when f1.status = 1 then f1.date else 

f2.date end as date
      from ForgeRock f1
 inner join ForgeRock1 f2 on f1.id = f2.id and 

(f1.Name!=f2.Name and f1.date!=f2.date) 

union all

Select f1.id,
      case when f1.status = 1 then f1.status else 

f2.status end as Status,
     case when f1.status = 1 then f1.amount else 

f2.amount end as rank,
      f1.Name,
      case when f1.status = 1 then f1.date else 

f2.date end as date
      from ForgeRock1 f1
 inner join ForgeRock f2 on f1.id = f2.id and 

(f1.Name!=f2.Name and f1.date!=f2.date)
```

Result:

```
id  Status  rank    Name          date
4     1     1500    ghanshyam   08/06/2015
1     0     4500    ram         04/02/2012
3     0     4500    gopal       04/02/2012
2     0     8000    shyam       15/11/2013
2     0     2000    radheshyam  05/09/2013
```

Now I want to update duplicate record id to new id
(i.e. In above result 2 is Duplicate,so change one record id from 2 to 21)

Comment: You will have more than one rows with `id=2` which one do you choose to insert? is `id` auto_increment?

Comment: No auto increment,I want to insert both rows but last row id to be updated as id=21

Comment: Then you woul have two rows wih `id=21`?!

Comment: Why It should be `21`? So if you have 3 rows with `Id = 2` all 3 should be updated to `21`?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

In *SQL-Server* you can try to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get duplicates and replace It with `Common Table Expression` in following:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
Select f1.id,
      case when f1.status = 1 then f1.status else 

f2.status end as Status,
     case when f1.status = 1 then f1.amount else 

f2.amount end as rank,
      f1.Name,
      case when f1.status = 1 then f1.date else 

f2.date end as date
      from ForgeRock f1
 inner join ForgeRock1 f2 on f1.id = f2.id and 

f1.Name=f2.Name 

     union all


 Select id,
      Status,
      amount,
      Name,
      date
      from ForgeRock
   where id not in (select distinct id from 

ForgeRock1)

union all

 Select id,
      Status,
      amount,
      Name,
      date
      from ForgeRock1
   where id not in (select distinct id from 

ForgeRock)

union all

Select f1.id,
      case when f1.status = 1 then f1.status else 

f2.status end as Status,
     case when f1.status = 1 then f1.amount else 

f2.amount end as rank,
      f1.Name,
      case when f1.status = 1 then f1.date else 

f2.date end as date
      from ForgeRock f1
 inner join ForgeRock1 f2 on f1.id = f2.id and 

(f1.Name!=f2.Name and f1.date!=f2.date) 

union all

Select f1.id,
      case when f1.status = 1 then f1.status else 

f2.status end as Status,
     case when f1.status = 1 then f1.amount else 

f2.amount end as rank,
      f1.Name,
      case when f1.status = 1 then f1.date else 

f2.date end as date
      from ForgeRock1 f1
 inner join ForgeRock f2 on f1.id = f2.id and 

(f1.Name!=f2.Name and f1.date!=f2.date)
), cte2 AS (
SELECT id, [status], rank, name, [date], RN
FROM(
SELECT id, [status], rank, name, [date], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id) RN
from (
Select f1.id,
      case when f1.status = 1 then f1.status else 

f2.status end as Status,
     case when f1.status = 1 then f1.amount else 

f2.amount end as rank,
      f1.Name,
      case when f1.status = 1 then f1.date else 

f2.date end as date
      from ForgeRock f1
 inner join ForgeRock1 f2 on f1.id = f2.id and 

f1.Name=f2.Name 

     union all


 Select id,
      Status,
      amount,
      Name,
      date
      from ForgeRock
   where id not in (select distinct id from 

ForgeRock1)

union all

 Select id,
      Status,
      amount,
      Name,
      date
      from ForgeRock1
   where id not in (select distinct id from 

ForgeRock)

union all

Select f1.id,
      case when f1.status = 1 then f1.status else 

f2.status end as Status,
     case when f1.status = 1 then f1.amount else 

f2.amount end as rank,
      f1.Name,
      case when f1.status = 1 then f1.date else 

f2.date end as date
      from ForgeRock f1
 inner join ForgeRock1 f2 on f1.id = f2.id and 

(f1.Name!=f2.Name and f1.date!=f2.date) 

union all

Select f1.id,
      case when f1.status = 1 then f1.status else 

f2.status end as Status,
     case when f1.status = 1 then f1.amount else 

f2.amount end as rank,
      f1.Name,
      case when f1.status = 1 then f1.date else 

f2.date end as date
      from ForgeRock1 f1
 inner join ForgeRock f2 on f1.id = f2.id and 

(f1.Name!=f2.Name and f1.date!=f2.date) )x
) x2
WHERE RN > 1
)
SELECT CASE WHEN cte1.Id = cte2.Id THEN REPLACE(cte1.Id, cte2.Id, CAST(cte1.Id AS NVARCHAR(20)) + '1') ELSE cte1.Id END AS Id, cte1.[Status], cte1.[rank], cte1.name, cte1.[date]
FROM cte1
LEFT JOIN cte2 ON cte1.[rank] = cte2.[rank] AND cte1.name = cte2.name
```

OUTPUT:

```
Id  Status  rank      name        date
4     1     1500    ghanshyam   2015-08-06
1     0     4500    ram         2012-04-02
3     0     4500    gopal       2012-04-02
2     0     8000    shyam       2013-09-11
21    0     2000    radheshyam  2013-05-09
```

Comment: But these is just example of  repeatation of id =2 .Actually any id can have repeatation so I just want to append '1' to id of only one record

Comment: Updated my answer, check It now, It will append '1' to all duplicate values.

Comment: How if no. Of tables more than 2

Comment: Getting in Sql Fiddle:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cte1 AS ( Select f1.id, case when f1.status = 1 then f1.status else f2.s' at line 1

Comment: As I wrote this is for SQL-Server, not for MySQL, you can change database in SQL fiddle from MySQL to SQL-Server.

Comment: As i want to run the Query in Sqlite android will it work?

Comment: i want to run the query in SQLite plz help